# What would cause Apache serving somepage.php/friendly-url yield 404 after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, apache2, http-status-code-404, friendly-url

My hoster has recently upgraded PHP to 5.3.8 and now all my installations that use a URL pattern like `somefile.php/friendly-url` yield a 404 ErrorDocument (where `somefile.php` is an actual existing PHP file which is supposed to handle the rest of the path). How do I best go about fixing this? What is the directive that tells Apache to serve said URL even if only the `somefile.php` part is valid but not the whole location does not really point to an existing file?

BTW: No URL rewriting is involved… Also, the 404 is clearly generated by Apache, not any scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an `.htaccess` file to your public directory containing this line:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> Apache 2 users may use `AcceptPathInfo On` inside httpd.conf to define `PATH_INFO`.

Also have a look at the [Apache2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo).

Answer (score 0):

You probably had mod_rewrite configured differently before the upgrade... a similar thing happened to a sever I was working on about 2 months ago.  Check out [mod_rewrite](http://knol.google.com/k/seo-friendly-url-or-pretty-url-using-apache-mod-rewrite#Need_for_URL_reWrite) and see if this is what you need.

Comment: No, as I said, no URL rewriting is involved. At all.

Comment: Srry, then maybe it is the [config file](http://www.radwin.org/michael/blog/2002/11/hiding_php_extensions_in_a.html) which was hiding the extensions before

Comment: No, the extension was not hidden, it was visible. It’s just that now, the PHP script does not get executed.